# scoverage exclude packages for test vs integration test

Tags: scala, build, sbt, scoverage

in my build.scala i have

```
coverageExcludedPackages in ThisBuild := ".*dao.*"
```

which works great for excluding the package from coverage however i want to be able to exclude and include based on the type of tests I'm running.

For instance i run `sbt test` and `sbt it:test` my test is mainly unit test where as it:test has integration test that talks to the DB and i want that to show up in the coverage report when running `sbt coverage it:test && sbt coverageReport` but not be in the report for `sbt coverage test && sbt coverageReport`

there are some settings like

```
lazy val testSettings = Seq(
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "smoke,it,test",
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.5.7" % "test"
  ),
  testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("-oDF"),
  coverageExcludedPackages in Test := ".*dao.*"
)
```

where i tried to move the exclusion so that its only part of the `test` settings and not part of the `it:test` settings but it seems then to ignore the exclusion all together when I try that.